# Problem with Rails Installfest, what do I enter to correct issue? libreadline6-dev (issue)

Tags: apt, package-management, mount, dpkg, git

I keep getting this error when using the first step of the Installfest.

The line is:

`sudo apt-get install autoconf automake bison build-essential curl git-core libapr1 libaprutil1 libc6-dev libltdl-dev libreadline6 libreadline6-dev libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev libtool libxml2-dev libxslt-dev libxslt1-dev libyaml-dev ncurses-dev nodejs openssl sqlite3 zlib1g zlib1g-dev`

I receive:

```
Reading package lists… Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information… Done
Note, selecting ‘git’ instead of ‘git-core’
Note, selecting ‘libreadline-dev’ instead of ‘libreadline6-dev’
Note, selecting ‘libxslt1-dev’ instead of ‘libxslt-dev’
Note, selecting ‘libncurses5-dev’ instead of ‘ncurses-dev’
Package libreadline6 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package ‘libreadline6’ has no installation candidate
```

---

After that message I entered:

```
dpkg --list|grep libreadline    (at the suggestion of someone online)
```

I was returned:

`ii  libreadline7:amd64                         7.0-3                               amd64        GNU readline and history libraries, run-time libraries`

---

The link to the site is below, the issue arises with the code in Step 1. "libreadline7" in the code a few lines above is actually highlighted in red if that helps. Thanks guys and gals!

http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/linux

Comment: What it your Ubuntu version? And what is the version described in your manual?

Comment: @N0rbert  My Ubuntu version is 18.04 LTS. There was no specification in the installfest manual as to which version to operate on, just simply Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to remove `libreadline` version from `apt-get` command and use universal one - `libreadline-dev`.

So the complete command would be

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf automake bison build-essential curl git-core \
libapr1 libaprutil1 libc6-dev libltdl-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-0 \ 
libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev libtool libxml2-dev libxslt-dev libxslt1-dev \
libyaml-dev ncurses-dev nodejs openssl sqlite3 zlib1g zlib1g-dev
```

Then follow [InstallFest guide](http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/linux).

But I recommend to use Ruby `2.4.4` on **step 4** (as it is [marked **stable** on official site](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/)).

Comment: @N0bert Since I already entered the in-question command yesterday, would I simply run the above code in it's entirety, or do I need to try and remove libreadline bit and then run the above code in full? Thanks again!

Comment: @erik You can run this full command. If some stuff is already installed, it will skip them. Also consider to use stable ruby 2.4.4 (not pre-EOL 2.3 as in guide).

Comment: @N0bert  Thanks for the help! It seems to be looking good, thanks again buddy!

Comment: @N0bert I started the beginning of Step 4 with your instructions. Once all was said and done, the following message was what was at the very bottom of the output:       ` Install of ruby-2.4.4 - #complete 
Ruby was built without documentation, to build it run: rvm docs generate-ri`                                            What do you think? Build or not?

Comment: It depends on how do you plan to use it. Some documentation is available online (for example on [RubyDoc](https://www.rubydoc.info/)). For offline usage you may build documentation locally.

Comment: @N0bert I'm just going through a free online web dev course, you'd probably know better than me lol, I'll take whatever you suggest. I'm going through The Odin Project if that helps.